# Event driven alarm with roll and pitch in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, app-inventor

I'm currently trying to learn the AppInventor2 tool, by coding a roll and pitch application similar to the one listed in app Inventor gallery ([Balance Meter](http://gallery.appinventor.mit.edu/#page%3DApp%26uid%3D36066001%26label%3DBalance%20Meter)).

What I want to do, is enhancing the rolling from the OrientationSensor, by triggering a sound on certain values reached.

So far I know that the rolling is marked from -90 to 90 degrees. Although I have declared a lower value e.g. 30 to 35 degrees, I get the sound triggered only on the leftwards rolling of the device, but not on the other side. I want it to be triggered when rolling occur form e.g. -30 to 35 degrees respectively.

The following image shows the blocks I've used:

[image]

Need to mention that orientation of app is in landscape mode only, with home button on right side.

Could anyone be kind enough to give me a clue to the right blocks to use, or to the logic I should be followed to make this work? 
Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the `random integer` block just use an `or` block to play sound if **roll > 30** or **roll < -30**

[image]

or if you only want to play the sound if roll is **between -35 and -30** or **between 30 and 35**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Taifun for your answer. Have tried both, with great success on the second version with a little modification to much my needs. Problem is it's not functional on the "pitch". Is it because I'm using the "AccelerometerSensor" reading the "zAccel" for the pitch or what?

Comment: without a screenshot I unfortunately have to say: *sorry, I don't know*... probably [this snippet](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2accelerometer) can help? What about accepting this answer and starting a new question with your new question and add a screenshot there?

Comment: your answer is accepted. Don't know if it is ok to repost a similar question with the "pitch" problem in the "zAccel" sensor, but if it is ok, I will post a screenshot too, if you are kind enough to help me out again.

Comment: guess your are right. Posted a new question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268426/event-driven-sign-with-pitch-in-app-inventor-2